# Symfony 2.0 Doctrine entities setter doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, setter

I have a database with a table Absence with fields: id, date, duration, user_id, typ_id.. I also have 2 tables User and AbsenceTyp. Everything with *_id is definied as a FK to the according table.

I generated getters/setters and updated my DB with the following commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities MyTestBundle
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

(Didn't generate any errors ...)

Now by saving an absence:

```php
$ab = new Absence();
$ab->setUserId(1);
$ab->setDate($date);
$ab->setDuration('0.5');
$ab->setTypId(2);

$em->persist($ab);
$em->flush();
```

...it lead to this sql-statment:

```
'INSERT INTO absence (date, duration, user_id, typ_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2014-07-07", "0.5", null, null]:
```

Setters for all the FKs aren't working... But Getters do their thing perfectly (e.g. getTypId())
Any ideas? Here my Absence-Entity:

```php
<?php
namespace MyTest\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AbsenceRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="absence", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_absence_user", columns=        {"user_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_absence_absencetyp", columns={"typ_id"})})
 */
class Absence
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=false)
 */
protected $date;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2, nullable=false)
 */
protected $duration;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
protected $user_id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyTest\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="absences")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
protected $typ_id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyTest\Bundle\MainBundle\Entity\AbsenceTyp", inversedBy="absences")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="typ_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $absenceTyp;

... // generated Getter / Setters
```

Comment: I also tried to change the naming strategy by:
naming_strategy: 
    doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore

Comment: You should probably first understand about associations in doctrine. You dont need both user_id and user properties. Same with typ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a JOIN relationship you must use the object setter to set the value of joined column. So for example, to set the value for user_id field you need to use ->setUser($userObject) setter instead of the setUserId().

Actually specifying the $user_id field in your entity is not required. It can be useful sometimes to do so, if you need to get access directly the user_id value during SELECTs from the database without having to fetch the User Object.

Your code could look something like this:

```
$user = new User(); //fake user or real user object if you have it fetched from db already
$user->setId(5);

$ab = new Absence();
$ab->setUser($user);
// ... set other fields
$em->persist($ab);
$em->flush();
```