# Symfony 2/Doctrine - set value of forgein key

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I had a problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972640/symfony-2-0-doctrine-entities-setter-doesnt-work). I followed the instructions of given solutions, but it generate another problem.

I've got two Entities:

```
namespace Acme\TyperBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Mecz
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mecz
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="druzyna1", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $druzyna1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="druzyna2", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $druzyna2;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bramki1", type="integer")
     */
    private $bramki1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bramki2", type="integer")
     */
    private $bramki2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="wyniktyp", type="string", length=2)
     */
    private $wyniktyp;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="datetime")
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typ1", type="float")
     */
    private $typ1;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typ1x", type="float")
     */
    private $typ1x;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typ2", type="float")
     */
    private $typ2;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typ2x", type="float")
     */
    private $typ2x;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typx", type="float")
     */
    private $typx;

     /**

      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Typy", mappedBy="meczid")
      */
     protected $meczid;

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
     }



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set druzyna1
     *
     * @param string $druzyna1
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setDruzyna1($druzyna1)
    {
        $this->druzyna1 = $druzyna1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get druzyna1
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDruzyna1()
    {
        return $this->druzyna1;
    }

    /**
     * Set druzyna2
     *
     * @param string $druzyna2
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setDruzyna2($druzyna2)
    {
        $this->druzyna2 = $druzyna2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get druzyna2
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDruzyna2()
    {
        return $this->druzyna2;
    }

    /**
     * Set bramki1
     *
     * @param integer $bramki1
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setBramki1($bramki1)
    {
        $this->bramki1 = $bramki1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bramki1
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBramki1()
    {
        return $this->bramki1;
    }

    /**
     * Set bramki2
     *
     * @param integer $bramki2
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setBramki2($bramki2)
    {
        $this->bramki2 = $bramki2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bramki2
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getBramki2()
    {
        return $this->bramki2;
    }

    /**
     * Set wyniktyp
     *
     * @param string $wyniktyp
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setWyniktyp($wyniktyp)
    {
        $this->wyniktyp = $wyniktyp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wyniktyp
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getWyniktyp()
    {
        return $this->wyniktyp;
    }

    /**
     * Set data
     *
     * @param \DateTime $data
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setData($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

     /**
     * Set typ1
     *
     * @param float $typ1
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setTyp1($typ1)
    {
        $this->typ1 = $typ1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typ1
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTyp1()
    {
        return $this->typ1;
    }

      /**
     * Set typ2
     *
     * @param float $typ2
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setTyp2($typ2)
    {
        $this->typ2 = $typ2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typ2
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTyp2()
    {
        return $this->typ2;
    }

      /**
     * Set typ1x
     *
     * @param float $typ1x
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setTyp1x($typ1x)
    {
        $this->typ1x = $typ1x;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typ1x
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTyp1x()
    {
        return $this->typ1x;
    }

      /**
     * Set typ2x
     *
     * @param float $typ2x
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setTyp2x($typ2x)
    {
        $this->typ2x = $typ2x;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typ2x
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTyp2x()
    {
        return $this->typ2x;
    }

      /**
     * Set typx
     *
     * @param float $typx
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setTypx($typx)
    {
        $this->typx = $typx;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typx
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTypx()
    {
        return $this->typx;
    }

    /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add meczid
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $meczid
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function addMeczid(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $meczid)
    {
        $this->meczid[] = $meczid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove meczid
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $meczid
     */
    public function removeMeczid(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $meczid)
    {
        $this->meczid->removeElement($meczid);
    }

    /**
     * Get meczid
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMeczid()
    {
        return $this->meczid;
    }

    /**
     * Add mecz
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecz
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function addMecz(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecz)
    {
        $this->mecz[] = $mecz;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove mecz
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecz
     */
    public function removeMecz(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecz)
    {
        $this->mecz->removeElement($mecz);
    }

    /**
     * Get mecz
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMecz()
    {
        return $this->mecz;
    }

    /**
     * Add mecztyp
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecztyp
     * @return Mecz
     */
    public function addMecztyp(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecztyp)
    {
        $this->mecztyp[] = $mecztyp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove mecztyp
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecztyp
     */
    public function removeMecztyp(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Typy $mecztyp)
    {
        $this->mecztyp->removeElement($mecztyp);
    }

    /**
     * Get mecztyp
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getMecztyp()
    {
        return $this->mecztyp;
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Acme\TyperBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Typy
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Typy
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_kuponu", type="integer")
     */
    private $id_kuponu;

     /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_meczu", type="integer")
     */
    private $id_meczu;



    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="typ", type="string", length=2)

     */
    private $typ;

     /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="stawka", type="float")
     */
    private $stawka;

      /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mecz", inversedBy="meczid",cascade={"persist"})
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_meczu", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $meczid;




    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set id_kuponu
     *
     * @param integer $idKuponu
     * @return Typy
     */
    public function setIdKuponu($idKuponu)
    {
        $this->id_kuponu = $idKuponu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id_kuponu
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdKuponu()
    {
        return $this->id_kuponu;
    }

    /**
     * Set id_meczu
     *
     * @param integer $idMeczu
     * @return Typy
     */
    public function setIdMeczu($idMeczu)
    {
        $this->id_meczu = $idMeczu;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id_meczu
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdMeczu()
    {
        return $this->id_meczu;
    }

    /**
     * Set typ
     *
     * @param string $typ
     * @return Typy
     */
    public function setTyp($typ)
    {
        $this->typ = $typ;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get typ
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTyp()
    {
        return $this->typ;
    }

    /**
     * Set meczid
     *
     * @param \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Mecz $meczid
     * @return Typy
     */
    public function setMeczid(\Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Mecz $meczid = null)
    {
        $this->meczid = $meczid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get meczid
     *
     * @return \Acme\TyperBundle\Entity\Mecz 
     */
    public function getMeczid()
    {
        return $this->meczid;
    }

    /**
     * Set stawka
     *
     * @param float $stawka
     * @return Typy
     */
    public function setStawka($stawka)
    {
        $this->stawka = $stawka;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stawka
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getStawka()
    {
        return $this->stawka;
    }
}
```

So I want to use this code to insert data to table:

```
 $mecz = new Mecz();
       $mecz->setId($id_meczu);

        $typs = new Typy();

        $et = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $typs->setIdKuponu($id_kuponu);
        $typs->setMeczid($mecz);
        $typs->setTyp($typ);           
        $typs->setStawka($stawka);

        $et->persist($typs);
        $et->flush();
```

And i get exception:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO Mecz (id, druzyna1, druzyna2, bramki1, bramki2, wyniktyp, data, typ1, typ1x, typ2, typ2x, typx) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]:
```

I don't know why, because i want to instert data to "Typy" table not "Mecz" table. Can anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following:

You have the field `Typy::meczid`, but this field does (from the perspecitve of Doctrine) not hold a numeric ID, but a reference to a `Mecz` instance. Therefore the name `meczid` is misleading, it should be `Typy::mecz`. I'd recommend renaming the field and the accessors for the sake of consistency.

Now the `Typy` entity expects a `Mecz` entity to be set, which you do: You create a `new Mecz()`, and assign it to `Typy` with `$typs->setMeczid($mecz);`. BUT: The `Mecz` instance is lacking lots all properties except the ID. (By the way, in Doctrine IDs should generally be autogenerated, not by the business logic.) As the Typy entity depends on Mecz, the Mecz must be persisted first, so its reference can be stored with the Typy.

Bottom line: You must fill the generated `Mecz` with the missing properties.

Hint: To avoid that this type of error happens on the DB level, you should use [Symfony's entity validation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). This will allow a much better error handling; both during development, and in production.